# Is the term "nagware" considered sexist?

Tags: terminology, offensive-language

I have a suspicion, though I'm not certain, that the verb "nag" may be considered sexist. Is the term "nagware", describing software that constantly asks the user to pay for it, considered sexist?

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: This is why: [urbandictionary = Nag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nag)

Comment: I expect that you will find someone here to posit offense for anything you say, but the Urban Dictionary notwithstanding, bosses of both sexes can nag you to meet your deadlines. In this case, we don't even personify software.

Comment: If you are saying that nagging is characteristic of women, then you're the one being sexist. And if you avoid using the word for this reason, then you're only perpetuating the stereotype.

Comment: Oh, I thought we were talking about ***nagwear*** http://www.horsechannel.com/images/horse-keeping-images/horse-cooler.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No—in this context, nagging is just persistent and annoying urging. It’s not exclusive to women.

There is a negative stereotype that women nag their male children and partners. *Nagging wife* or *nagging mother* could therefore be considered sexist, but *nagging software* or *nagware* is not.